# How to use use 1 button to show images on a gui with a delay between each image (for animating)

Tags: java, user-interface, animation

I am relatively new at coding and trying to make a GUI which displays a short 3-image animation. To do this I am displaying the images as ImageIcon's in a JLabel on a GUI and trying to get the program to rotate through the 3 images with a timed delay of 300 milliseconds between each image after a button is pressed. I am not getting any errors with the code I have, however when I run it, it doesn't show the animation as an animation. It just displays the last image of the animation. It is almost like the JLabel isn't being updated until the entire actionperformed method is run.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Timer;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AnimatedGui extends JFrame{
    //The imageIcon and JLabel thing is how I am adding the images to the GUI
    JButton button1;
    private ImageIcon image1;
    private ImageIcon image2;
    private ImageIcon image3;
    final JLabel label1 = new JLabel();




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new AnimatedGui();

    }

    public AnimatedGui(){

        //Declare Variables
        button1 = new JButton();
        image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Stick man Standing.jpg"));
        image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Stick man first step.jpg"));
        image3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Stick man ending.jpg"));
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();       
        Dimension dim = tk.getScreenSize();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        label1.setIcon(image1); 

        //setting up gui
        this.setSize(500,600);      
        int xPos = (dim.width)-(this.getWidth());
        int yPos = 0;       
        this.setLocation(xPos,yPos);
        this.setResizable(false);               
        this.setTitle("Trying to Animate");     
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ListenForButton listenButton = new ListenForButton();
        button1.addActionListener(listenButton);        
        button1.setText("Walk");        
        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(button1);
        this.add(panel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Here I am trying to get it to wait 300 ms between showing each image
    //but it only shows the final image in the animation
    private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int period = 300;
            long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTime<300){ 
                label1.setIcon(image2);
            }
            while(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTime<600&&System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTime>300){    
                label1.setIcon(image3);
            }
            while(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTime>600){ 
                label1.setIcon(image1);
            }       

        }

    }   

}
```

if anyone could help me out with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You are just updating the image when the button is pressed. Try to use a gif if you want to show animation. Replacing images that frequently is not the way to show moving images.

Comment: So these particular images were made in paint and this is a proof of concept if i wanted to do a longer animation. How would I turn them into a gif, and how would I then get the GUI to display the gif when the button is pressed? @clinomaniac

Comment: You can use many tools to make a gif. Just search for how to make a gif. If you want to animate it on button click, you can show a jpg to start with and then switch to gif on button click. You can use as many images as you want to make your gif.

Comment: Thank you @clinomaniac, the gif worked!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: So say at the end of the gif, I want it to stop on a particular image. How do I do that? if i just add in a setIcon() method containing the image I want it to end on after the gif, it skips over the gif and just shows the final image. @clinomaniac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use many tools to make a gif. Just search for how to make a gif. If you want to animate it on button click, you can show a jpg to start with and then switch to gif on button click. You can use as many images as you want to make your gif. Top stop it again, you will need to replace it with the jpg of the image you want to stop on. Stopping a gif gets more complicated so I would recommend replacing it with the jpg.

Comment: So I am trying to replace it with a jpeg image at the end. When I do this, it only shows the final jpeg image and skips over the gif entirely. I am putting the final jpeg switch after the gif inside the action performed method. Sorry to bother you and thanks for your help so far @clinomaniac

Comment: How do you determine the end? You can set a timer for it to wait but I have never done it on the front end so not sure how it will behave. Another option is to have another action to stop it which would be another action listener for some other event to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure out how to use a timer